# Can a stustain pedal be modified for alternative uses?

Tags: guitar, keyboard, effects-pedal, keyboard-pedals, sustain

Is it possible to modify a MIDI sustain pedal to for example, a guitar pedal? If so, would this be practical at all? If not, what could be an alternative use of such pedal?

Comment: By "MIDI sustain pedal" do you mean a pedal with a *MIDI* connector (such as [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector#/media/File:Cherry-Schneider-MF2-5-Pin-DIN-Connector.jpg)? Or just a standard TRS connector connected to a MIDI keyboard/controller?

Comment: Theoretically, you could use it as a switch for a guitar (which you would have to build yourself). However, it would be annoying to use it as a guitar pedal. You can't you use the piano pedal to gradually change the level of a guitar effects because the piano pedal only has a on and off state. Furthermore, a guitar pedal should turn on and off quickly but a piano pedal is damped and is slow to turn on/off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what a MIDI sustain pedal is, in comparison to most other sustain pedals. But most are simple switches, working in a similar way to a doorbell push. Press the pedal, contact made, release, contact lost. There are many *effects* pedals that will use an extra pedal such as this, to do all sorts of different things *to* that effects pedal, but on its own, the only thing I can come up with is a sort of kill switch.

Comment: Still assuming the OP is talking about standard sustain pedals (those with trs connectors), using them as switches could be a problem anyway: most (barely *decent*) pedals have some levels of sensitivity, as they are potentiometers, fundamentally, and there's also the controversy of polarity: on some pedals the passage of current is when they are down, others when they're up, that's why on more recent keyboards you have to connect them *before* switching on, so that they can recognize the polarity and then adapt accordingly.

Comment: Polarity is often switchable, unless it's a very cheap pedal. Yes, trs won't work as *efficiently* as a standar ts, which is a very simple on/off switch.

Comment: I actually meant TS, what do you mean by "won't work as efficiently"? Btw, yes, they usually have a switch, unless when they're bundled with the keyboard.